# Calcular número de vendas de um vendedor

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, diagrama

Estou realizando um trabalho acadêmico sobre BD, no caso estou desenvolvendo um banco de dados para uma distribuidora de alimentos. Estou em dúvida de como posso realizar a contagem da quantidade de vendas que um vendedor realizou a fim de calcular o valor da comissão. Ademais, criei uma entidade para QUANTIDADE, como posso saber qual a quantidade de um produto em uma ocorrência de pedido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para te ajudar a criar um modelo de entidades, pense assim:

> O que é quantidade? Ela contém atributos, dados que a descrevem? Ou ela é uma propriedade de outra coisa que a contém?

No seu caso, observe que a quantidade é na verdade um atributo do Pedido, pois quando você pede algum produto, você normalmente informa a quantidade desejada, concorda?
Dessa forma, não faz sentido criar uma entidade para quantidade, pois ela é apenas um número, faz mais sentido colocá-la como atributo da entidade Pedido, e a partir do pedido você já saberia as ocorrências de solicitações de um produto.

Comment: Mas no caso um pedido possui vários produtos diferentes, se eu colocar quantidade como atributo de pedido eu estarei limitando a quantidade de todos os produtos e não somente de um?

Comment: Nesse caso, você tem um relacionamento de um pedido com vários produtos e um produto em vários pedidos (many to many). Quando temos essa situação, é necessário criar uma tabela que relaciona o pedido com o produto, você pode chamá-la de PedidoProduto. Nela vai existir o id do produto e o id do pedido (referências para as tabelas pedido e produto), o que cria esse relacionamento entre essas entidades! Você criará um registro nessa tabela para cada produto contido no pedido. Se quiser, eu adiciono essa explicação na resposta.

Comment: Farei uma fusão de entidades então? Nesse caso a quantidade de um produto não interfere em outro?

Comment: Você criará uma nova entidade chamada ProdutoPedido, mantendo as entidades Produto e Pedido, ou seja, não é uma fusão, é a criação de uma nova entidade. A entidade Quantidade você remove, pois ela irá existir como uma propriedade da entidade Pedido, assim como você criou o  "valor total" e "código". Na nova entidade ProdutoPedido você irá apontar para Produto e Pedido, pois ela terá as propriedades id_produto e id_pedido, cada apontamento sendo um relacionamento 1 para n.

Comment: ProdutoPedido estará relacionado com Pedido e Produto?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Ele é que permite que você tenha vários produtos relacionados a um pedido.

Comment: Quais são os atributos da entidade ProdutoPedido?

Comment: Somente um identificador código? Entendi o que está falando, mas estou em dúvida de como essa entidade funciona.

Comment: Essa entidade terá apenas o id do produto e o id do pedido, por isso ela é chamada de ProdutoPedido. Ela simplesmente relaciona produtos com seus respectivos pedidos.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar uma tabela para cada produto que conta com seu histórico, entradas e saídas com o número do pedido definido como uma chave estrangeira.

Assim você consegue calcular a quantidade de cada produto retirada por pedido.

E atribuindo o pedido ao vendedor, seria simples de saber quanto de um produto ele(a) vendeu.

De qualquer forma, quantidade não é bem uma entidade e como foi colocado pela @Giuliana Bezerra:

> Dessa forma, não faz sentido criar uma entidade para quantidade, pois ela é apenas um número, faz mais sentido colocá-la como atributo